# Java and video codecs

Tags: java, video, codec, divx

I want to build java app, which will record some application. Could you provide me any links or solutions, which codecs should I use for windows , mac and linux, should I use three diffirent codecs for each OS or there is standard codecs for every OS. I want to create video in divx codecs or avi, but preffered is flv. I'll be thankfull if you help me.thanks. (and: it has to be java app)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/formats.html) for a java codec pack for JMF

Answer (score 0):

Well...you can refer Java Complete Reference book where there is a chapter dedicated to multimedia...maybe you'll get some info from that...I'm not sure about any other resource...